# What is return value of `data` from `call()`

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have the following function which usually reverts the transcation due to `success` is `false` which is returned from the `call` function. But I want to know why it's value is false so I inspected it's returned `data` value but it's showing nothing in console. I am using hardhat.

```
function fillQuote(
    )
        internal 
    {
        require(sellToken.approve(spender, type(uint256).max));
        (bool success,bytes memory data) = swapTarget.call{value: 1000000}(swapCallData);
        console.log("is swap success: ",string(data));

        require(success, 'SWAP_CALL_FAILED');
        
    }
```

Does anyone knows how to inspect value of `data` or any other way to know why the `call` function is failing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use abi.decode to decode the data.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Target {
  function someFunc() external returns(uint[] memory numbers, string memory name) {
    numbers = new uint[](3);
    numbers[0] = 10;
    numbers[1] = 20;
    numbers[2] = 30;
    name = 'hahah';
  }
}


contract Test {
  function action(address addr) external {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) =  addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunc()"));
    if (success) {
      (uint[] memory numbers, string memory name) = abi.decode(data, (uint[], string));
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And you can use `try/catch` to catch errors to see what kind of error messages were raised if you make an external call with the contract instance, like `Target(targetContractAddress).someFunc()`, but can't catch if you use `addr.call`.

Check example [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/try-catch/).